# Force flask to wait for Asynchronous JS Function before Reload

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, amazon-s3, flask

I have a submit button for upload images and information. When the submit button is called the following happens at the same time:

- POST request to the Flask app. (for updating info)
- JS:(at same time as above)

  - GET request to the Flask app for presignedPost.
  - Once presignedPostRequest received upload file to s3.

What happens is that the POST request to Flask finishes and tells the page to reload. When this happens the AJAX request gets cancelled (if its still in process). Sometimes my code works and other times it doesnt. By adding a time.sleep(3) to the Flask app I can wait for the s3 upload to finish and everything works. This is not a good solution.

How can I force Flask to wait until the JS function is complete?

I'm trying to save my server by having users send directly to s3. Should be faster for them.

Waiting for 3sec works. Looking at xhr logs in chrome tells what is happening.

```
preventDefault() doesnt work because there are 2 requests happening. 


@users.route("/account", methods=['GET', 'POST'])
@login_required
def account():
    form = UpdateAccountForm()
    if form.validate_on_submit():
        if form.picture.data:
            # picture_file = save_picture(form.picture.data)
            # current_user.image_file = picture_file
            time.sleep(3)
        current_user.username = form.username.data
        current_user.email = form.email.data
        db.session.commit()
        flash('Your account has been updated!', 'success')
        return redirect(url_for('users.account'))
    elif request.method == 'GET':
        form.username.data = current_user.username
        form.email.data = current_user.email
    image_file = url_for('static', filename='profile_pics/' + current_user.image_file)
    return render_template('account.html', title='Account',
                       image_file=image_file, form=form)
```

ctrl + K is not working so here's a short JS version. ctrl + K is going to my url bar in Chrome. :-(

```
function uploadfile() {
    **Get PresignedPostRequest**
    **Upload file to s3**
} 

document.getElementById("submit").onclick = function() {uploadfile()

};
```

I know why this is working this way but I don't know of a reasonable solution. Do I have to change my design pattern? I'm using flask because I'm weaker on JS.

Just graduated a Bootcamp so I'm pretty new to this. 
I could run everything through my app but it would be harder on my server...
I think I could use socket.io but it's another layer of complication....

Thanks for looking!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I changed my code to a different approach. Then I returned a few days later to get help from a friend and my code worked fine.  Here is what I used to solve the problem. Idk why this didn't work for two days...

```
document.getElementById("accountForm").onsubmit = function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    uploadfile();

    document.getElementById('accountForm').submit();
```